# Multithreaded loop does not work on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

This is going to be very basic but we are running into an issue and are not able to narrow down the issue. Hoping someone will shed some light to it.

we have a simple static class

```
public static class SomeLogger
{
    private static ConcurrentQueue<LogObject> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<LogObject>();
    private static bool isRunning = false;        
    public static void Start()
    {
        if (isRunning) return;
        Task.Run(() => Process());
    }
    public static void Stop()
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public static void AddToQueue(LogObject obj)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(obj);
    }

    public static void Process()
    {
        isRunning = true;

        using (var p = new SomeClass())
        {
            while (isRunning)
            {
                //see if something is in the queue object if yes process it 
                if(queue.TryDequeue(out LogObject d))
                {
                    //Do some stuff
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We invoke this class in our Application Event Listener on Start
 - it Invokes SomeLogger.Start
 - Set the isRunning to true

everything is fine till now

we run the web application and call SomeLogger.Add() multiple time to do logging

But when we are running this locally i.e. on iisexpress the while loop is picking up all the add the queue event and processing them.

While when the same is execute on the IIS on our server, only the first Add and Last Add message from queue is getting picked.??

We are not sure why? Anything you guys see wrong in the code above..

Environment: 
Simple Asp.Net Web API
SomeClass is a kafka producer

Comment: What is `// do some stuff`? Sure no exceptions are thrown?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you reset `isRunning`.

Comment: Probably not the solution, but you may want to replace if (queue.TryDequeue(...)) with while (queue.TryDequeue(...)).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong and agree with Patrick that the problem might be in the processing logic.  Just recommendation use ```Task.Delay(1000).Wait()``` as opposed to ```Thread.Sleep(1000)``` for consistency and I would make the ```Process()``` method private.  This has nothing to do with your issue though so apologies.  Since this happens on server and not local it may be an issue with the connection.  Can you verify that ```AddToQueue``` is being hit each call? It feels like the code is good man so my guess is there's an error like Patrick said or something else.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane forgot to add the stop method in the sample above. we do have a stop methos that gets invoked when the application shuts down.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Confirmed that AddToQueue is getting invoked on the server. I can also see the queue object count increasing everytime it does that. the isrunning flag also comes as true inside the AddToQueue method

Comment: Other thought : You may also want to replace the Thread.Sleep() statement with a Task.Delay(), as Thread.Sleep() blocks the Thread, which then cannot be used for anything else.

Comment: @PatrickHofman //do some stuff is basically doing a p.ProduceAsync() (send the message to the kafka broker). I did check that it is not failing anywhere.. but let me add some more exception handling to it. The other thing is that i am seeing the logs coming in just fine from my local that uses the same kafka broker and topic

Comment: @PatrickHofman you were right..digged deep into the ProducerAsync and one of the innerexceptions is showing an error that 'system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.dll' used by kafka is missing in our DEV environment. The code was silently ignoring the error.

Comment: It always does ;) @fireholster

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks for the task sleep suggestion. changed it to use that. and also for confirming that my code for handling the queue was ok.. Appreciate it

Comment: The only wrong thing I can see in the code is that `Start` and `Stop` methods aren't thread safe. That is if they're called concurrently for some reason (but we don't know as a caller code isn't presented) the combination of Start, Stop, Start can be reordered in context of state modification which will cause Logger be finally in the stopped state.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a solution using TPL's Dataflow library

```
public static class SomeLogger
{
    private static readonly BufferBlock<LogObject> _buffer = new BufferBlock<LogObject>();
    private static Task _consumer;
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public static void Start()
    {
        if (_cts != null && !_cts.IsCancellationRequested) return;

        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _consumer = ConsumeAsync(_buffer, _cts.Token);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }

    public static void AddToQueue(LogObject log)
    {
        SendToBuffer(_buffer, log);
    }

    private static void SendToBuffer(ITargetBlock<LogObject> target, LogObject log)
    {
        target.Post(log);
    }

    private static async Task ConsumeAsync(IReceivableSourceBlock<LogObject> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (await source.OutputAvailableAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            var log = await source.ReceiveAsync();

            // do some stuff
        }
    }
```

You can even add to the buffer with `AddToQueue` and they won't be processed until `Start` is called

Comment: What problem does this fix?